# git checkout will not remove staged files that were never committed

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am learning git and was was surprised by the fact that staged files created while being in topic branch are not deleted when checking out to the master.

For example:

```
git checkout -b topic
nano newfile.txt
git add newfile.txt
git checkout master // newfile.txt is still in the working directory, even though it was created in topic branch
```

I am well aware of `git clean` command, it's just that I expected that all files that were never committed are removed if you checkout to a different branch.

Am I missing something here or is this the expected behaviour of git?

Comment: Try to think of that in another way: what if you loose all the changes that you actually need? You can always adjust the working directory to the staged version, but git minimizes your risk to loose unstaged changes.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053757/checkout-another-branch-when-there-are-uncommitted-changes-on-the-current-branch

Answer (score 5):

It is expected behaviour. If I had to describe it (and anyone is welcome to dispute my explanation), I would say that because your `newfile.txt` has not yet been checked in and nothing in the `master` branch is associated with `newfile.txt` yet, `git` should not be removing files that it is not responsible for yet. Under normal circumstances, we do not want `git` creeping around and modifying files that have not been added to the repo yet. On the other hand, if the file has been added to the repo, it is fair game for `git` to be removing changes.

That said, as you already suggested, it is possible to remove these types of files in the directory via the `git clean` commands.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `git clean` after a checkout, you can still switch to a different branch while discarding current changes with the new (experimental) command [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch).
That would require Git 2.23 (Q3 2019)

```
git checkout -b topic
nano newfile.txt
git add newfile.txt
git switch -f master # newfile.txt would be gone.
```

That requires only one command (`git switch`) instead of two (`checkout` + `clean`)